# How to hide credentials for multi-user python script that accesses a DB on a different server?

Tags: python, postgresql, credentials

I am using psycopg2 to access a PostgreSQL DB on a separate server and create a CSV file with the results of the SQL.  I want to create a way to let my employees on the same network run these reports with my script without giving them access to the credentials used to log in to the PSQL DB.  Several Google results later, and I'm still left wondering what the best way to do this is.  I am open to ways outside of the Python Environment.  What is the safest way of hiding credentials for this situation?

Comment: The "safest" way depends on the capabilities and intentions of the employees, and the value of the data.  Rather than trying to secure the credentials it might be better to create the reports as stored procedures and create a user that can *only* call these procedures, or create views for the report data and again, limit the user to querying those views.

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want to share your script with your colleagues what you can do is to encrypt the credentials and save to a text file which will be shipped with your script. Then in your script you will read this text file decrypt the encrypted credentials and used to connect to the DB. This should be enough for your use case which is to "...`without giving them access to the credentials used to log in to the PSQL DB`"
Please try following steps:

1. Install [fernet](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/) cryptography library: pip3 install cryptography

2) Encrypt your password and save the encrypted string in a '.ini' file:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
key = Fernet.generate_key()
cipher_suite = Fernet(key)
cipher_text = cipher_suite.encrypt(b"MyPassword&#)__")
```

.ini file content (for the above example):

```
[DEFAULT]
password = AAAAABfPGwDK7-5uz_YxUtkfWohehtg53lgvMX5NbC4lgU_trZGI9gGioqdLKUVp6ZaAQdVKurirQ-dQ5MsAPNk87wsA74Tng==
```

3. Read the encrypted file and decrypt to use as your password

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

config = ConfigParser()
config.read('src/params.ini')
encrypted = config.get('DEFAULT', 'password')

plain_text = cipher_suite.decrypt(encrypted)
print(plain_text.decode("utf-8"))
```

Please keep in mind that we have many other options (more secure ones) to achieve what you need although this one is simple and it will fulfill your requirement.